# Ordering Data Frame Columns Then Pasting Row Name

Tags: r

I have a data frame that looks like this:

```
> testdata
          topic1 topic2 topic3 topic4 topic5
church     0.011  0.003  0.001  0.001  0.012
of         0.094  0.085  0.098  0.063  0.051
the        0.143  0.115  0.159  0.083  0.097
appearance 0.000  0.000  0.002  0.005  0.040
restrain   0.000  0.000  0.000  0.000  0.000
```

What I need to do is create a new data frame that is also 5 rows by 5 columns where each column is the ordered row names of this data frame. In other words, I need to order the data frame by each column in descending order, then print the row names on top of that column, essentially to get the ranked words in order. For this example, the data frame I need would be

```
> testdata_word_ranks
                 topic1       topic2       topic3       topic4       topic5
church              the          the          the          the          the
of                   of           of           of           of           of
the              church       church   appearance   appearance   appearance
appearance   appearance   appearance       church       church       church
restrain       restrain     restrain     restrain     restrain     restrain
```

Here is my failed attempt at assigning the columns of `testdata_word_ranks` above to a new data frame:

```
for(i in 1:nrow(testdata)){
  minidf = data.frame(rownames(testdata), testdata[,i])
  assign(paste0('testdata_word_ranks$topic', i),
         as.vector(minidf[order(minidf[,2], decreasing = TRUE),]$rownames.testdata))
}
```

Just for your information, this data is coming from a topic model on a particular corpus.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could index the row names by the order of each column:

```
matrix(row.names(test.data)[apply(-test.data, 2, order)], nrow(test.data))
#      [,1]         [,2]         [,3]         [,4]         [,5]        
# [1,] "the"        "the"        "the"        "the"        "the"       
# [2,] "of"         "of"         "of"         "of"         "of"        
# [3,] "church"     "church"     "appearance" "appearance" "appearance"
# [4,] "appearance" "appearance" "church"     "church"     "church"    
# [5,] "restrain"   "restrain"   "restrain"   "restrain"   "restrain"
```

Comment: Alternative attempt - `replace(testdata,,rownames(testdata)[sapply(-testdata,order)])`